# What does "time" mean in football/soccer context?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "time" mean in football (soccer) context?

77 min Dzeko with a golden opportunity to make it four! Rooney lost the ball in the City half and Silva burst forward. Silva **timed the ball** to Dzeko perfectly, and the Bosnian lashed a shot across De Gea's body. De Gea saves with his feet and it goes for a corner.

Comment: It just means Silva ***correctly predicted*** exactly where Dzeko would be by the time the passed ball arrived in his vicinity (presumably both players were moving at the time, so Silva would have to take account of ***time / speed*** as well as ***direction*** when making his pass ***to*** Dzeko, otherwise they would lose possession rather than score a goal (or corner, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario is that Silva saw where Dzeko was and hit the ball with the correct weight of shot and the correct direction to arrive at where Dzeko could hit it. The same idiom is used in other sports as well.